# App icon not displaying after installing APK in OPPO A55

Tags: android, installation, apk, oppo

I am installing apk on my device OPPO A55 (Android 12), but after a successful install message, the app icon does not display in the menu list or Application Manager.

Below are some screenshots of the process and configuration of the device.

[image: When I click on APK]

[image: APK Successful Installed message]

[image: Device Configuration]

Comment: Is the APK developed by you? Because otherwise it is not a topic for Stackoverflow (Android user questions belong to https://android.stackexchange.com). Apps don't have to have an app icon. If an app has no main activity then it has no app icon (e.g. if it is an Android-TV only app installed to an Android phone). Check the app list in Android settings.

Comment: Yes, this apk is developed by me.

Comment: Then why do you post useless screen shots instead of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and other details of the app source code?